# how to install angular2 in asp.net 4 project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

i'm learning how to build angular2 environment in asp.net 4 project

i follow the document on https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/asp-net-4.html .

but the document seems out of date

who can give me the link how to build the currently angularJs2 in asp.net 4 mvc project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the angular2 site https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

so there will be a first page called "index.html" but in your case, you can use Home/Index view.

Comment: i think nodejs can't work well in the asp.net project,because vs should compile the ts file while  the config doesn't match the json file,so what should i do

Comment: @CeryDe Better to setup the project with node js and move required folder under your mvc project and give correct path. Then run through the vs and it should work.